# Binding json response to label

Tags: ajax, json

```
  public JsonResult GetPrice(List<int> modelValues)
    {
        List<int> model = new List<int>();
        try
        {foreach(var d in modelValues)
           model.Add(d); 
        }


        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

function GetDetail() {
    var jsonUrl = Home/GetPrice";

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: jsonUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {

    }
});
```

I want my values present in model to display in label.It should be done by binding data using ajax call. Can someone please suggest me a solution? Label id="name" in html file.

Comment: Label id="name" in html file.

Comment: Is it anything more than a line in your `success` function which says `document.getElementsByName('name')[0].textContent = data.someField;`?